# Anonymously forwarding emails

Tags: canada, email, social-media, proxy

I was thinking about making this as a side project to generate traffic on my Canadian website...

Let's say I create a service similar to yopmail.com whereas I allow users to generate email addresses on-demand. This service would allow you to send and receive emails with no sign-up required (for let's say, throwaway emails for account creation). Let's say that, hypothetically, an user of the site sends threats to somebody or that other types of illegal content is being sent trough the system. Assuming that the website hosting all of it has a no-logging policy, what is the worst that can happen?

If, on the other hand, access-logging is required by law, how can it protect me? I have an history of having legal problems with a similar idea of mine and I would like to understand what is my wrongdoing.

Many thanks to anyone reading!

Comment: If you're encountering actual legal problems, you need an actual lawyer, not a bunch of random weirdos on the Internet.

Comment: ^especially so if you've had *"an history of having legal problems with a similar idea"*

Comment: i wasnt thinking about putting any of that stuff online, real question was kind of a question about how logging can really help me, this scenario applies to alot of services online

Comment: The short answer is that if you have some obligation to store logs, you would be able to fulfill that obligation. Generally, some kind of immunity is provided to service providers to shield them from the actions of their users/customers, but if the service providers are negligent, they can face liability. As others said, you'll probably need an actual lawyer to help you understand your situation.

Answer (score -3):

It would only seem the intent of falsely generating traffic to your website is to sell a false representation of your websites popularity. Therefore defrauding your client. Not a sensible thing to do.

If you want to gain traffic to your site I recommend Google mastering which will index your website for free and properly. It's a simple step by step process and it isn't breaking the law.

If your website doesn't work for 'whatever' reason it may be better focusing your efforts on a good business model as opposed to lying about your ratings.

Comment: Welcome to Law.SE.  Please [take the tour](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour), and note in particular that this Stack Exchange explicitly tries to avoid providing "advice."

Comment: Sorry Law.SE bot, but I'm trying to prevent a crime and to be honest I'm confident your site policy is supposed to prevent this content being displayed at all as its clearly seeking advice to commit a crime

Comment: I am not a bot, I am a moderator.  And questions about this site's policy take place at https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you have an issue with a question please use the Flag or Close links.  Visit https://law.stackexchange.com/help to learn more about these.

Comment: Sorry, are you posting me a link, as a moderator to this site, to take this problem elsewhere? Is this a joke. The OP is asking advice on how to commit fraud. By leaving it up you are propagating it

Comment: Is this answer a joke? Google created Gmail, possibly to get extra traffic to Google. Adding additional side services to a business to get more traffic/users/clients on the main business is a far cry from "fraud"

Comment: @Victor no the answer is not a joke and fraud is illegal. Endorsing the behaviour makes you equally as fraudulent and perpetuating illegal activity. The reason the OP clearly states he has legal problems with similar projects is because it is ILLEGAL regardless of your opinion. The LAW is clear on the subject matter, if you want to contest the law approach legislators and ask them to change the law, until then, the answer is, its illegal

Comment: @Barb It is clear from the original question that OP has legal problems relating to *retention policies*. Here, you bring up the unrelated concept of *fraud* without justification. Fraud has many essential elements (in Canada, it includes that the complainant owned something of value, that the culprit deprived the complainant of something of value or was put at risk of losing something of value, and that the deprivation must have been caused by deceit, falsehood, or some other fraudulent means), which are neither present here nor result from the offering of additional services by a business.

Comment: @Victor fortunately the law stipulates what fraud is, not the opinions of layman's. Do not endorse this behaviour because it is illegal

Comment: @Barb Yes, the law stipulates what fraud is, and it isn't related to this question.